# Received task, but not success not fail message, how to fix?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

When I run celery task I got this. Windows 10, redis celery 5.

```
[2021-10-29 19:08:18,216: INFO/MainProcess] Task update_orders[55790152-41c0-4d83-8874-4bd02754cb77] received
[2021-10-29 19:08:19,674: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 7196 calling self.run()
```

/

```
My celery.py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'src.settings.local')

BASE_REDIS_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

app = Celery('src')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.broker_url = BASE_REDIS_URL

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print("Request: {0!r}".format(self.request))

app.conf.beat_scheduler = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'

app.conf.worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss = True
```

my tasks.py

```
import random
from celery import shared_task
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
import datetime

from config.models import Config


@shared_task(name="update_orders")
def update_orders():
    print('Delayed')
    obj = Config.objects.all().order_by("-id").last()
    obj.orders_last_time_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
    obj.save()
    return True
```

My settings

```
# CELERY STUFF
CELERY_BROKER_URL           = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND       = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT       = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER      = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER    = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE            = TIME_ZONE


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "django-db"
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery 4.0+ does not officially support window. But it still works on window for some development / testing purposes.

Try installing gevent:

```
pip install gevent
```

And then run

```
celery -A projectname worker -l info -P gevent
```

This works for me on window 10 + celery 5.1.2 + python 3.10